# Is there any way to use Symfony PHP framework with Bigtable / Cassandra DB?

Tags: php, symfony1, cassandra, bigtable

Is there any bridge/native method to use the Bigtable / Cassandra DB arhitecture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Cassandra with the Thrift-Protocol. There is a nice PHP-Class to use Cassandra/Thrift with PHP:
http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-cassandra-php-wrapper-07-1979.html

But there is no plugin or something that allows you to use the default Model layer of Symfony. You will need to use a library like the linked wrapper-class